# Apache mod_proxy - Pass through from localhost to another domain?

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm not at all experienced when using proxies but hopefully this is possible.

I have apache running on my development machine which hosts a website (www.testdomain.com). I need to look at www.testdomain.com from my phone. I don't want to root my phone so all I can do is enter the IP address of my machine (10.8.0.1). The site hosted at www.testdomain.com won't work correctly as the default site in apache.

I need some way of passing through a request to 10.8.0.1 to www.testdomain.com without my phone having to look up the DNS record for www.testdomanin.com

Is this possible using mod_proxy? Is there something else that will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't really understand why can't you point your cellphone browser to www.testdomain.com.

Anyway, you could use a proxy, but I think a better approach would be to use a ServerAlias directive in your www.testdomain.com vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.testdomain.com
    ServerAlias 10.8.0.1
    (...)
```

If you still want to use a proxy, you could setup a different vhost for 10.8.0.1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.8.0.1
    ErrorLog ...
    TransferLog ...
    LogLevel warn

    # ReverseProxy
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        / http://www.testdomain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.testdomain.com/
    (...)
```

ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: putting testdomain.com in my mobile will do a domain lookup for it, which will take me to the live server and not my dev machine. The website I'm working on is built in a stupid way that will only work correctly with a known domain name.